# Using high refresh rate monitor with ubuntu

Tags: xrandr

I have 165hz monitor and I have one small problem..

Whenever I scroll on a page or move window in desktop etc, all of that is capped at 60 fps for some reason, instead of 165.

Is there way to get everything at the 165fps? This is the only problem i hate from switching from windows..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What graphics card  do you have, and are you using the proprietary drivers for it ?

Comment: GTX 1080 and I am using 375.39 drivers, Let me know if I should use some other ones. Let me clear that my mouse movement is at 165fps while other stuff is not.